# how to enlarge image onmouseover in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need help again. Displaying images on gridview is never been a problem to me but how can i enlarge my image onmouseover event in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript or jquery to perform the task.

Comment: JQuery still being JavaScript :P~

Answer (score 0):

erm...

If you will enlarge those images to a default heightXwidth i will consider using css and adding that class in the mouseover event... and removing it in the mouseout...

if you use JQuery you can add that css class like:

```
$('#elementID').addClass('enlarged'); <-- enlarged class resizes my image
```

and to remove the added class just:

```
$('#elementID').removeClass('enlarged');
```

if you dont use any javascript library, you can add a class using:

```
document.getElementById("elementID").className += " enlarged";
```

to remove it:

```
document.getElementById("elementID").className = document.getElementById("elementID").className.replace(/\benlarged\b/','')
```